# Java Itext pdf - java.io.IOException ...not found as file or resource

Tags: java, itext

This code is build and worked well After some time running this was error

[image]

```
   public class Ax {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("‪‪E:\\HelloWorld.pdf");

      PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader,
            new FileOutputStream("‪‪E:\\HelloWorld-Stamped.pdf"));

      Image image = Image.getInstance("C:\\Users\\Oliver\\Desktop\\user_access-512.png");

      for(int i=1; i<= pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); i++){

          PdfContentByte content = pdfStamper.getUnderContent(i);

          image.setAbsolutePosition(10f, 70f);

          content.addImage(image);
      }

      pdfStamper.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
 }
```

I used *itextpdf-5.4.1.jar* library

***How do i should solve this issue ?***

Comment: iText 5.4.1 is very old (april 13, 2013). Why don't you work with iText 7.1.2? Also: this error is not an iText exception. It's a `java.io.IOException` that you should be able to reproduce without iText. The file is either missing or access to it isn't available (e.g. the `E:` disk isn't mounted or you don't have access).

Comment: Thank you for your explain I can do it